# ImportError: cannot import name '_validate_lengths'

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-image

I have started learning Tensorflow. I am using Pycharm and my environment is Ubuntu 16.04. I am following the [tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/tensorflow-tutorial). I cross check the nump. It is up-to-date. I don't know the reason of this error.

> from numpy.lib.arraypad import _validate_lengths
>
> ImportError: cannot import name '_validate_lengths'

Need hint to resolve this error. Thank you.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from skimage import transform
from skimage import data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import numpy as np
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
import random

#listdir: This method returns a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by path.
# Return True if path is an existing directory

def load_data(data_dir):
    # Get all subdirectories of data_dir. Each represents a label.
    directories = [d for d in os.listdir(data_dir)
                   if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(data_dir, d))]
    # Loop through the label directories and collect the data in
    # two lists, labels and images.
    labels = []
    images = []
    for d in directories:
        label_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, d)
        file_names = [os.path.join(label_dir, f)
                      for f in os.listdir(label_dir)
                      if f.endswith(".ppm")]
        for f in file_names:
            images.append(data.imread(f))
            labels.append(int(d))
    return images, labels


ROOT_PATH = "/home/tahir/PhD Study/Traffic Signs Using Tensorflow/"
train_data_dir = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, "TrafficSigns/Training")
test_data_dir = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, "TrafficSigns/Testing")

images, labels = load_data(train_data_dir)

# Print the `images` dimensions
print(images.ndim)

# Print the number of `images`'s elements
print(images.size)

# Print the first instance of `images`
images[0]
```

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/3586

Answer (score 114, accepted):

I updated my skimage package.

```
pip install --upgrade scikit-image
```

And the problem was solved. It's a problem of version of Skimage, which is solved in 0.14.2. PLus, this version is quite stable.

```
    Installing collected packages: dask, scikit-image
  Found existing installation: dask 0.19.1
    Uninstalling dask-0.19.1:
      Successfully uninstalled dask-0.19.1
  Found existing installation: scikit-image 0.13.0
    Uninstalling scikit-image-0.13.0:
      Successfully uninstalled scikit-image-0.13.0
Successfully installed dask-1.0.0 scikit-image-0.14.2
```

Answer (score 5):

scikit-image 0.14.2 worked with numpy 1.16.3. I installed numpy first and then installed scikit image

Comment: now the previous error is gone but getting this new error: Got this error ImportError: cannot import name 'img_as_float32'. Using Version of Numpy: 1.17.0 & skimage: 0.13.0

Answer (score 4):

`pip install scikit-image==0.14.2 && pip install numpy==1.15`

Ref: [Here](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/3906#issuecomment-492039622)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, I did the following steps:

uninstall scikit-image

```
pip uninstall scikit-image
```

or

```
conda uninstall scikit-image
```

and then

```
pip install scikit-image
```

or

```
conda install -c conda-forge scikit-image
```

Comment: After following the above steps getting this error: ImportError: cannot import name 'img_as_float32'. Using Version of Numpy: 1.17.0 & skimage: 0.13.0, Python 3

Comment: If you are in a jupyter notebook, do not forget to add the --y argument, like !conda uninstall scikit-image --y or !conda install -c conda-forge scikit-image --y

Answer (score 1):

For me the magic dependency was:

```
pip install scikit-image==0.13.1
pip install numpy==1.15
```

For python 3.5 and python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

upgrade scikit-image to latest, OR
downgrade NumPy to 1.15.

```
 pip install -U scikit-image
```

or

```
 pip install numpy==1.15
```

if the pip isn't latest. You may need this:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

refer to [Getting ImportError: cannot import name '_validate_lengths' #3906](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/3906) .

Answer (score -1):

Seems I also had the same issue due to two versions installed sametime.

I solved it by uninstalling scikit-image multiple times till none was left.

```
pip uninstall scikit-image
```

Then Reinstall:

```
pip uninstall scikit-image
```

It worked for me.