# pandas and numpy not functioning properly after installing SHAP

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, python-import, shap

I'm new to python programming and want to install SHAP. After installing SHAP I'm getting error for basic codes, which were executing fine earlier(pandas and numpy).
My versions are 
python 3.7.1
conda 4.7.11
pd__version__ :'0.23.4'

I have gone through similar problems and tried to troubleshoot but now neither SHAP, nor numpy,pandas are working properly. 
I'm working in anaconda distribution for windows. And `pip install --upgrade` does not solve my problem.

```
#Explaining with SHAP
import shap

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-f08ae71e45dd> in <module>
      1 #Explaining with SHAP
----> 2 import shap

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shap\__init__.py in <module>
      9 from .explainers.gradient import GradientExplainer
     10 from .explainers.linear import LinearExplainer
---> 11 from .plots.summary import summary_plot
     12 from .plots.dependence import dependence_plot
     13 from .plots.force import force_plot, initjs, save_html

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shap\plots\summary.py in <module>
     13     pass
     14 from . import labels
---> 15 from . import colors
     16 
     17 # TODO: remove unused title argument / use title argument

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shap\plots\colors.py in <module>
      5 
      6 import numpy as np
----> 7 import skimage.color
      8 
      9 try:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\__init__.py in <module>
    174                              dtype_limits)
    175 
--> 176     from .util.lookfor import lookfor
    177     from .data import data_dir
    178 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\__init__.py in <module>
      6 from .apply_parallel import apply_parallel
      7 
----> 8 from .arraycrop import crop
      9 from ._regular_grid import regular_grid, regular_seeds
     10 from .unique import unique_rows

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\arraycrop.py in <module>
      6 
      7 import numpy as np
----> 8 from numpy.lib.arraypad import _validate_lengths
      9 
     10 

ImportError: cannot import name '_validate_lengths' from 'numpy.lib.arraypad' (C:\Users\z026355\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraypad.py)
```

Currently even pd.read_csv is not working

```
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\z026355\Desktop\Titanic")
with open("train.csv", encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as g:
    data = pd.read_csv(g)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-136-f58724e2278b>", line 2, in <module>
    data = pd.read_csv(g)

  File "C:\Users\z026355\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
    error_bad_lines=error_bad_lines,

  File "C:\Users\z026355\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 440, in _read
    filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression

  File "C:\Users\z026355\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 774, in __init__

  File "C:\Users\z026355\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 797, in _get_options_with_defaults
    Passed dialect overrides any of the related parser options

AttributeError: module 'pandas.compat' has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Upgrading or re installing pandas gives requirement already fulfilled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: cannot import name '\_validate\_lengths'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54241226/importerror-cannot-import-name-validate-lengths)

Comment: No it is not the same issue and also i have gone through this link before and tried pip install --upgrade but issue still persists.

Comment: you said you tried `pip install --upgrade` but you didn't say what package. Did you run `pip install --upgrade scikit-image`?

Comment: I have edited the question. Thanks for pointing out. My problem is with numpy, pandas and shap packages. I'm unable to upgrade pandas. I have mentioned my version in the question. This current version is not allowing me to ```read_csv```.

Comment: Did you run `pip install --upgrade scikit-image`?

Comment: Also experiencing the same issue, can not read csv. How was this resolved?